# Sentry Error When Deploying Django App On Mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi, sentry

I'm getting the following error when I try to deploy my django 1.3 app with Apache2 and mod_wsgi:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "sentry.errors"
```

Everything seems to be configured fine from Django's end. I can run it fine when I run ./manage.py runserver but when I try to run it through mod_wsgi it gives errors.

Thanks!

Comment: First, configure root logger to capture all messages in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is being logged, but there is no handler for that logger. This could be happening for a couple of different reasons. The message might not be logged when running via manage.py (perhaps DEBUG setting is different), or the code that sets up your handler is not being imported prior to the log message when running with mod_wsgi. To fix the problem, take a look at the code that initializes your log handler, and determine when it is executed.